# PHP Warning: simplexml_load_string(): namespace error : Namespace prefix soap on Envelope is not defined in

Tags: php, soap

We had someone write a script to pull shipping quotes from a shipper for us.  It works, but we keep getting this error in our logs:

```
[10-Jul-2015 17:02:13] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): namespace error : Namespace prefix soap on Envelope is not defined in /home/public_html/shipping/loomisexpress.php on line 321

[10-Jul-2015 17:02:13] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope ><soap:Body><RateInqRespons in /home/public_html/shipping/loomisexpress.php on line 321

[10-Jul-2015 17:02:13] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/shipping/loomisexpress.php on line 321

[10-Jul-2015 17:02:13] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): namespace error : Namespace prefix soap on Body is not defined in /home/public_html/shipping/loomisexpress.php on line 321

[10-Jul-2015 17:02:13] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope ><soap:Body><RateInqRespons in /home/public_html/shipping/loomisexpress.php on line 321

[10-Jul-2015 17:02:13] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /home/sjenkins/public_html/shop/includes/modules/shipping/loomisexpress.php on line 321
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
$responseXml = str_replace('xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"',"",$responseXml);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($responseXml);
```

Would love to know how to fix this error.

Additional code:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ser="http://tempuri.org/RATEINQ/Service1"> 
    <soapenv:Header/> 
    <soapenv:Body> 
      <ser:RateInq> 
        <ser:LoginName>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_USERNAME.'</ser:LoginName> 
        <ser:Password>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_PASSWORD.'</ser:Password> 
        <ser:ShipperAccountNumber>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_ACCUNTNUMBER.'</ser:ShipperAccountNumber> 
        <ser:FromPostalCode>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_FROM_POSTAL_CODE.'</ser:FromPostalCode>
        <ser:ToPostalCode>'.$to_postal.'</ser:ToPostalCode> 
        <ser:ToCity>'.$add_city.'</ser:ToCity> 
        <ser:ToProvinceCode>'.$add_state.'</ser:ToProvinceCode> 
        <ser:ToCountryCode>'.$country_id.'</ser:ToCountryCode> 
        <ser:ServiceType>ALL</ser:ServiceType> 
        <ser:PickupDate>'.date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currdate . ' + 1 day')).'</ser:PickupDate> 
        <ser:UOM>I</ser:UOM> 
        <ser:Pieces>'; 
        for($i=0; $i<$ttl; $i++)
        {
            for($j=0; $j<$products[$i]['quantity']; $j++)
            {
     $xml .= '<ser:Piece> 
               <ser:Weight>'.$products[$i]["weight"].'</ser:Weight> 
               <ser:Length>0</ser:Length> 
               <ser:Width>0</ser:Width> 
               <ser:Height>0</ser:Height> 
         </ser:Piece>';
            } 
         }
       $xml .= '</ser:Pieces> 
         <ser:ValuationAmount>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_VALUATION_AMOUNT.'</ser:ValuationAmount> 
         <ser:IsNonPack>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_ISNONEPACK.'</ser:IsNonPack> 
         <ser:IsDangerousGood>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_ISDANGEROUSGOOD.'</ser:IsDangerousGood> 
         <ser:IsSaturdayDelivery>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_ISSATURDAYDELIVERY.'</ser:IsSaturdayDelivery> 
         <ser:IsFragile>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_FRAGILE.'</ser:IsFragile> 
         <ser:IsResidential>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_RESIDENTIAL.'</ser:IsResidential> 
         <ser:IsDutiable>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_CHAINOFSIGNATURE.'</ser:IsDutiable> 
         <ser:IsDTP>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_DTP.'</ser:IsDTP> 
         <ser:Language>'.MODULE_SHIPPING_LOOMISEXPRESS_LANGUAGE.'</ser:Language> 
      </ser:RateInq> 
    </soapenv:Body> 
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: For some reason the str_replace explicitly removes the namesapce definition.

Comment: I know NOTHING about soap... could you tell me exactly how I need to modify the code?

Comment: "could you tell me exactly how I need to modify the code" - sorry, I can't. You have to ask the developer why the namespace declaration has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this case as I don't have such warning @ my side.

```
function getMemberName($string)
{
    $XMLRequest = simplexml_load_string($string);
    return $XMLRequest->Member->Firstname .' '. $XMLRequest->Member->Secondname
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line of code you show with `str_replace` is for some reason removing part of the XML (SOAP) response, making it invalid. The message in the logs is warning you about that invalid data.

If the rest of the code works, you could just leave it alone - it's a Warning, not an Error. However, the fact that this is happening may be a sign that the rest of the code is poorly written - it is presumably relying on that line because the person who wrote it didn't know the proper way to deal with XML Namespaces.